# How is atomic_dec_if_positive atomic?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, atomic

So I am reading `atomic.h` from Linux source code from [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h?v=3.5) (found it on google. I am not sure if it's legit) and I just can't wrap my mind around this:

how is this atomic?

```
static inline int atomic_dec_if_positive(atomic_t *v)
{
  int c, old, dec;
  c = atomic_read(v);
  for (;;) {
    dec = c - 1;
    if (unlikely(dec < 0))
      break;
    old = atomic_cmpxchg((v), c, dec);
    if (likely(old == c))
      break;
    c = old;
  }
  return dec;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a scenario in which you think it behaves in a non-atomic manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the functions `atomic_read()` and `atomic_cmpxchg()`, which surely somewhere will be implemented in assembly language using atomicity features of the microprocessor's instruction set.

It first reads a value and makes sure it is positive, stores the read value in `c`, the decremented value in `dec` and calls `atomic_cmpxchg()` which will atomically do the following: "write `dec` in `*v` only if the value in `*v` is equal to `c`, and return the old value in `*v`". That way you make sure that the value in `*v` was not changed between the two atomic calls. If it fails and the return value was different from the expected contents of `*v`, it retries the whole process.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see it before :). The most important part: "write `dec` in `*v` only if the value in `*v` is equal to `c`" and `c` is a value which has been red at the start of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The following line

```
c = atomic_read(v);
```

means at this point in time we know the value of the atomic_v variable == c. We
decrement c to give us our required value.

```
dec = c - 1;
```

Obviously if the number is not positive and 0 is not positive we cannot
decrement it.

```
if (unlikely(dec < 0))
        break;
```

Now we try and change our known old result with the expected result

```
old = atomic_cmpxchg((v), c, dec);
```

This is defined as

```
int atomic_cmpxchg(atomic_t *v, int old, int new);
```

If we write it out as follows and assume that the whole function is atomic. We have

```
int atomic_cmpxchg(atomic_t *v, int old, int new) {
  &v->counter = &v->counter == old ? new : old;
  return old;
}
```

Note, I'm treating `v` as an integer, on x86 it's a struct. At this point we
know that at the point of the the atomic operation happening we get the
old value. Our expected old value is `c`, so if this is the case then we have
successfully decremented the value, return the result.

```
if (likely(old == c))
        break;
```

If not we need to reset our expectataion ie our start point, we're decrementing a new value `c` not the old one we had when last entered the `for(;;)` loop

```
c = old;
```

The important part here is that this is in a loop, this loop will continue until it succeeds to decrement the value or the value is non positive.